# Trouble sending hyperlink via json

Tags: android, json, sms, gson

I use Gson classes in my android apps to flatten out ojects and send them over REST to the server and back using HTTP posts and responses.  It has always worked well.

But in new app that I am writing I'm trying to do the same thing but using SMS messages instead of HTTP Posts.  For instance I have a class ...

```
class LocReturn
{
    public String error;        //one char y = error
    public String accuracy;
    public String hyperlink;
    public String stationary;   //one char y = stationary
    public String speedmph;
    public String speedkph;
    public String bearing;
}
```

Before I flatten the class, the hyperlink string gets the following value . . .

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&t=h&q=loc:31.7898,-111.0354
```

However when I examine the json string I see that the hyperlink has been changed to . . .

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?z\u003d17\u0026t\u003dh\u0026q\u003dloc:31.7898,-111.0354
```

Also, the SMS send is getting a NullPointer Exception.

The code that send the SMS message is . . .

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

String jsonstring = gson.toJson(myReturn);

String SMSBody = "###2" + jsonstring;


DebugLog.debugLog("Mole is sending Back: " +  " num= " + GlobalStuff.Mobileno + " SMSBody= " + SMSBody, false);

SmsManager
    .getDefault()
    .sendTextMessage(GlobalStuff.Mobileno, null, SMSBody, null, null);

DebugLog.debugLog("After SMS Send " + SMSBody, true);

finish();
```

So, (1) I can't see why I'm getting the NullPointer and (2) why is the hyperlink getting changed and does that have anything to do with it.
Thanks,
Gary
EDIT: the new json object creation...

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();
```

did indeed keep the hyperlink from being modified however the nullPointerException continues.  It is definitely the sendText line that is causing the exception as when I substitute SMSBody for "hello world" it works fine.  The contents of SMSBody is...

```
###2{"accuracy":"Excellent","bearing":"","error":"n","hyperlink":"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=17&t=h&q=loc:31.7898,-111.0353","speedkph":"","speedmph":"","stationary":"y"}
```

this is somehow causing the nullPointerException

Comment: Post the logcat output showing the NPE and let us know which line of code is causing it.

Comment: Also, try `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().disableHtmlEscaping().create();` to prevent the encoding change.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question for future googlers . . .

I forgot that SMS stands for SHORT Message Service.  My message was too long and, guess what happens when you send too long a message in SMSManager.sendTextMessage ?  You get a nullPointerException (instead of getting a MessageTooLong exception).

Gary